# Display image from resources by binding -WPF

Tags: wpf, image, resources

I have an icon on resources that it key is: `xxx`

I want to bind it to an image in xaml..

1:

```
  <Image Source="{x:Static p:Resources.xxx}"></Image>
```

2:

```
  <Image>
     <Image.Source>
         <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding x:Static p:Resources.xxx}"/>
        </Image.Source>
   </Image>
```

3:

```
 <Image Source=" {Binding x:Static p:Resources.xxx,Converter={StaticResource IconToBitmap_Converter}}"></Image>
```

4:

```
 <Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding x:Static p:Resources.xxx,Converter={StaticResource IconToBitmap_Converter}}"/>
    </Image.Source>
 </Image>
```

The above ways does not work, how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Image source from Resources in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377431/set-image-source-from-resources-in-wpf-application)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First you must add your Image into a Resource File in the Solution Explorer. Next you must set the Build Action of your Image to Resource and then you can use it in the XAML Code like this:

```
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="name" UriSource="Resources/yourimage.bmp" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Image  Source="{StaticResource name}"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

First:
Add resources rsx 
then:
add images as images to the resource file and set the image build action to Resource.
Now you can access the images like this:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/image.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may implement your own Markup extension and use it as follows:

```
<Image Source="{ex:ImageSource {x:Static p:Resources.xxx}}"></Image>
```

The MarkupExtension `ImageSource` may look like this:

```
public class ImageSource : MarkupExtension
{
    private readonly object source;

    public ImageSource(object source) => this.source = source;

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Binding sourceBinding = source is Binding binding ? binding : new Binding() { Source = source };
        MultiBinding converterBinding = new MultiBinding() { Converter = new SourceConverter() };
        converterBinding.Bindings.Add(sourceBinding);

        return converterBinding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }

    private class SourceConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => BitmapToSource(value[0] as Bitmap);

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotSupportedException();

        private BitmapImage BitmapToSource(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                memory.Position = 0;
                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapimage.BeginInit();
                bitmapimage.StreamSource = memory;
                bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapimage.EndInit();
                return bitmapimage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```