# Set Image source from Resources in WPF application

Tags: wpf, image, wpf-controls

Can anyone show me how can I set source to image from Resource in XAML. Currently I have

```
 <Image x:Name="img" Panel.ZIndex="1" Source="D:\Img100.jpg"  Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

I want Image Source to be come from Resources.

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First you will have to include the image in your project with [BuildAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) `Resource`

Then you can use it directly in your Image

```
 <Image Source="Img100.jpg"/>
```

Or make a reusable resource of the image

App.xaml (or other resource dictionary)

```
<Application.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="myImage" UriSource="Img100.jpg" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Element:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource myImage}" />
```

Comment: A small modification: <BitmapImage x:Key="myImage">pack://application:,,,/Resources/Img100.jpg</BitmapImage>

Comment: @Sonhja why is the pack syntax needed?

Comment: @DaveInCaz it's a pack resource for a XAML resource. You can see details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf