# Image wont show in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I am new to C# and WPF and was trying to make a very basic program that show a picture. So in the XAML file I put in this code:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="184,143,0,0" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="image.jpg"/>
```

It shows up in the editor (Visual Studio) but when I run the program is appears to be gone! Here is the entire code:

```
<Window x:Class="Follow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="184,143,0,0" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="bp.jpg"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks for your help, I've been looking but can't seem to find the answer!

Comment: Set the image file's Build Action to `Resource` (in the Properties Window in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/bp.jpg"
```

If your image in some folder then use:

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/FolderName/bp.jpg"
```

If the image is in your `resources` folder and its `buid action` is set to `Resource`. You can reference the image in `XAML` as follows:

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/bp.png"
```

Comment: It still shows up in the editor but not when I run the program! I tried all three of those, no luck.

Comment: Where you copied your image in the application..?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, under the resources where your image is stored, make sure the build action is set to resource. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15378245/1229237) is a similar question with a more detailed answer.